# Structuring tests for inherited architecture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest

I have an MVC project in which a controller is derived from two base classes in the following structure:

```
Global Base Controller
|
|--------------------|
Type1               Type2
|                    |
|--------------------------------------|
Controller1/Controller2         Controller3/Controller4
```

I want to setup my unit tests so that I only test any overridden method in controller1/2/3/4 so that I stick to the DRY principals. This means that if I added tests into the `Global Base Controller` they will be applied further down the chain.

What is the best way of achieving this with NUnit/msTest?

I have tried following the same structure with the tests as per the following example, but the base tests are not picked up:

```
public class ControllerTestClass<T>
{
    public class ForThisMethod
    {
        [Test]
        public void WhenThisCondition_HasThisValue()
        {
            Assert.IsAssignableFrom<T>("");
        }
    }
}

public class UnitTest2 : ControllerTestClass<String>
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ForThisMethod2
    {
        [Test]
        public void WhenThisCondition_HasThisValue()
        {
            Assert.True(true);
        }
    }
}
```

With the above structure, I see the following in Test Explorer:

[image: Result from Test Explorer]

**Note:** I know that testing in this way will require the developer of new functionality to add the additional tests. This is fine and will be written into the project notes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to think your tests in the same way as you are for your implemenatation code but less "formal" way.  You are trying to overcomplicate your tests code. The danger is that you might endup spending same time and effort managing your test code as your implementation code.

What I do is to use inheritance for common functionality and so that I can reduce writing same code (I believe you are trying to achive same here) but I know that I have to repeat some test code which is fine becouse it means I dont have to manage them.

In general if you have to write too much of same tests methods then you prob. need to rethink your implementation design and prob. need to introduce code saperation using IoC/DI or similar technique. This way your generic code will only have limited number of tests and all the other code which are specific to different functionality will be tested in isolcation. (Hope this makes sense :) )